# SQL column value to table name

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

In my SQL database, I would like to make a general purpose soft link table. Perhaps something similar the following:

```
create table soft_link(
  id uniqueidentifier, 
  name varchar(255),
  LINK uniqueidentifier,
  TABLE varchar(255),
  primary key(id));
```

Say I have object "b_object" in some other table in the database. The LINK column would be the the unique identifier of b_object, and TABLE would be the table in which b_object is stored within the database.

Now I want to make a single stored procedure "sp_ResolveSoftLink". This method will take an id of a soft link, look up the LINK and TABLE columns of the soft link, and then use the TABLE and LINK to query for b_object.

The following is NOT proper SQL syntax, but hopefully it helps illustrate my question. I want to combine these two queries into a single stored procedure and return the result of the second query:

```
select LINK, TABLE from soft_link where id = xxxxxx
select * from TABLE where id = LINK
-- return the result of the second select query
```

**FUNDAMENTAL QUESTION:** How/can I use the varchar return from one query to form another query in the same stored procedure in SQL?

Comment: This is called dynamic SQL.  You need to construct the SQL query as a string and then execute it.  The exact syntax depends on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Stored procedure like this.

Here, First you have to store value of LINK and Table in variable and then use these variable to form another Dynamic Query

```
CREATE PROC spName
@id INT
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @LINKValue uniqueidentifier, @TABLE varchar(255),@SQL varchar(max)

  SELECT @LINKValue = LINK , @TABLE = TABLE 
  FROM soft_link
  WHERE soft_link id = @id

  SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM';
  SET @SQL = @SQL +' ' + @TABLE
  SET @SQL = @SQL +' ' + 'WHERE ID ='  +' ' + @LINKValue

  PRINT @SQL   -- SEE Here This is what you actually Want
  --EXEC (@SQL)  --Then Execute this

END
```